# Attempt to get Voice in Text Format Causes Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When i try in emulate is working but when i try in device it return a error how to solve this problem Here is my code 
i want to get user voice in text format

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SpeechRecognizerUI speech = new SpeechRecognizerUI();

        await speech.Recognizer.PreloadGrammarsAsync();

        SpeechRecognitionUIResult result = await speech.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

        if (result.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.RecognitionResult.Text);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

error is 
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800455BC 
in  this line `SpeechRecognitionUIResult result = await speech.RecognizeWithUIAsync();`

Comment: Do you have the correct permission set in the AppManifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means that the language isn't supported. I'm not sure what your language settings are but you can get the recognizer with your locale using this (swap en-GB with the culture you want)

```
var localRec = InstalledSpeechRecognizers.All
                       .Where(r => r.Language == "en-GB").FirstOrDefault();
```

Then set your recognizer with that language

```
if(localRec != null)
  recognizer.Recognizer.SetRecognizer(localRec);
else
  MessageBox.Show("Recognizer with the language not found");
```

If you don't explicitly set the locale above then the system will use the language set in the phone's Speech settings.